# BCH Code - Find conjugacy class of minimal polynomial with degree outside of the field

Tags: coding-theory

I am looking over an example from some notes I found online:

> Given a binary BCH(15,7,5) codeword **r** = 100000001000000, we have
>   **r(x)** = 1 + x<sup>8</sup>
>
> When calculating the syndromes for this codeword polynomial, you get
>   the following syndromes:
>
> S<sub>1</sub> = **r($\alpha$)** = 1 + $\alpha$<sup>8</sup> =
>   $\alpha$<sup>2</sup>
>
> and
>
> S<sub>3</sub> = **r($\alpha$<sup>3</sup>)** = 1 + $\alpha$<sup>24</sup> =
>   $\alpha$<sup>7</sup>

I am confused as to how the syndromes were "reduced" in the final step.

The conjugacy classes are setup as follows:

> let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^4 + x + 1$
>
> {0} => $x$
>
> {1} => $x + 1$
>
> {$\alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^4, \alpha^8$} => $x^4 + x + 1$
>
> {$\alpha^3, \alpha^6, \alpha^9, \alpha^{12}$} => $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x
> + 1$
>
> {$\alpha^5, \alpha^{10}$} => $x^2 + x + 1$
>
> {$\alpha^7, \alpha^{11}, \alpha^{13}, \alpha^{14}$} => $x^4 + x^3 + 1$

Where I am confused is:

1. How $1 +\alpha^{8}$ is reduced to $\alpha^2$.  Is it because $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^8$ are in the same conjugacy class?  And if so, then:
2. How is $1 +\alpha^{24}$ is reduced to $\alpha^7$. $\alpha^{24}$ has a degree higher than any polynomial GF(16).  How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Apparently, I need to go back to algebra.

$\alpha^4 + \alpha + 1 = 0$

Therefore $\alpha^4 = \alpha + 1$

And then it's easy
$1 + \alpha^8 = 1 + (\alpha^4)^2 = 1 + (\alpha + 1)^2 = \alpha^2$

Similar logic follows for my second question

Comment: Correct. Well done.